# Huge dropped frames on a 4k video when using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to use `exoplayer` to play my local 4k Video file. However, the frame rate dropped a lot. I tried to limit the video size and buffer time, but it did not seem to work.

```
DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
        .setBufferDurationsMs(1000, 1000, 500, 500)
        .build();

DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(getContext());
DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder builder =
        new DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder(getContext());
builder.setMaxVideoSize(300, 500);
trackSelector.setParameters(builder);


trackSelector.setParameters(builder.build());
exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getContext())
        .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
        .setLoadControl(loadControl)
        .build();
```

Do you guys have any suggestions? It can be reproduced easily with ExoPlayer demo app. The video was played well without any issue by using `MediaPlayer`, but I want some enhanced features of ExoPlayer.

P/s: the video can be downloaded here https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/9062.

This is what I got from logcat:

```
2021-06-16 21:55:20.659 24844-25131/ W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ima
2021-06-16 21:55:20.673 24844-25131/ W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
2021-06-16 21:55:20.674 24844-25131/ W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
2021-06-16 21:55:20.683 24844-25131/ W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
2021-06-16 21:55:20.741 24844-25131/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp43
2021-06-16 21:55:20.754 24844-25131/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 1/32 for video/mp4v-es
2021-06-16 21:55:20.754 24844-25131/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
2021-06-16 21:55:20.754 24844-25131/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/64 for video/mp4v-es
2021-06-16 21:55:20.759 24844-25131/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
2021-06-16 21:55:20.762 24844-25131/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
2021-06-16 21:55:20.783 24844-25131/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv7
2021-06-16 21:55:20.786 24844-25131/ W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv8
2021-06-16 21:55:20.820 24844-25131/ I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
2021-06-16 21:55:20.849 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.850 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.851 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.851 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.867 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.869 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.869 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.869 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.890 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.892 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.892 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.893 24844-25131/ D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4034, video/avc] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [on7xelte, SM-G610F, samsung, 27]
2021-06-16 21:55:20.897 24844-25131/ I/ACodec:  [] Now uninitialized
2021-06-16 21:55:20.897 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [] onAllocateComponent
2021-06-16 21:55:20.902 24844-25135/ I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
2021-06-16 21:55:20.907 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Loaded
2021-06-16 21:55:20.909 24844-25134/ D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0xca11d808, reason connectToSurface
2021-06-16 21:55:20.910 24844-25134/ I/MediaCodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 25440257
2021-06-16 21:55:20.910 24844-25134/ D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0xca11d808, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
2021-06-16 21:55:20.910 24844-25134/ D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0xca11d808, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
2021-06-16 21:55:20.912 24844-25135/ E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010
2021-06-16 21:55:20.912 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: can't find wfdsink-exynos-enable
2021-06-16 21:55:20.914 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: codec does not support config priority (err -1010)
2021-06-16 21:55:20.914 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: codec does not support config operating rate (err -1010)
2021-06-16 21:55:20.920 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Loaded->Idle
2021-06-16 21:55:20.936 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Idle->Executing
2021-06-16 21:55:20.938 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Executing
2021-06-16 21:55:20.952 24844-25131/ I/ACodec:  [] Now uninitialized
2021-06-16 21:55:20.952 24844-25141/ I/ACodec: [] onAllocateComponent
2021-06-16 21:55:20.954 24844-25141/ I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
2021-06-16 21:55:20.957 24844-25141/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.aac.decoder] Now Loaded
2021-06-16 21:55:20.958 24844-25141/ I/ACodec: codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
2021-06-16 21:55:20.959 24844-25141/ I/ACodec: codec does not support config operating rate (err -2147483648)
2021-06-16 21:55:20.960 24844-25141/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.aac.decoder] Now Loaded->Idle
2021-06-16 21:55:20.978 24844-25141/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.aac.decoder] Now Idle->Executing
2021-06-16 21:55:20.978 24844-25141/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.aac.decoder] Now Executing
2021-06-16 21:55:20.984 24844-25141/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.aac.decoder] Now handling output port settings change
2021-06-16 21:55:20.990 24844-25141/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.aac.decoder] Now Executing
2021-06-16 21:55:23.547 24844-25134/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] signalFlush
2021-06-16 21:55:23.547 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ExecutingState flushing now (codec owns 7/8 input, 7/8 output).
2021-06-16 21:55:23.547 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Flushing
2021-06-16 21:55:23.736 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,0)
2021-06-16 21:55:23.736 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,1)
2021-06-16 21:55:23.736 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Executing
2021-06-16 21:55:25.541 24844-25134/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] signalFlush
2021-06-16 21:55:25.542 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ExecutingState flushing now (codec owns 7/8 input, 7/8 output).
2021-06-16 21:55:25.542 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Flushing
2021-06-16 21:55:25.737 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,0)
2021-06-16 21:55:25.737 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,1)
2021-06-16 21:55:25.737 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Executing
2021-06-16 21:55:27.519 24844-25134/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] signalFlush
2021-06-16 21:55:27.519 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ExecutingState flushing now (codec owns 7/8 input, 7/8 output).
2021-06-16 21:55:27.519 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Flushing
2021-06-16 21:55:27.712 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,0)
2021-06-16 21:55:27.712 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,1)
2021-06-16 21:55:27.712 24844-25135/ I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Executing
2021-06-16 21:55:28.574 24844-24852/ I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=252KB, data=204KB
2021-06-16 21:55:28.576 24844-24852/ I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=218KB, data=150KB
```

Comment: If you are testing on a Samsung J7 Prime, that phone was released in 2016. The video size and frame rate (1080x1920 at 60 fps) exceeds the recommended specs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#video-encoding I would transcode to the HD 720p specs and see if the video plays correctly.

Comment: @MorrisonChang well, with MediaPlayer, it worked quite well.

Comment: So there isn't anything in the logcat?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I added some logs to the question. Please check it.

Comment: I do see "DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010" in the log. Two things to look at (1) ExoPlayer appears to be using `OMX.google.h264.decoder` which I believe is a S/W decoder. Check what is logcat output of MediaPlayer (2) I would change the Exoplayer demo app to rotate the video (as it is vertical) and see if that changes anything.